# Proof of Alternating Binomial Coefficient Identity relating

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I am looking for a proof of the following binomial identity. I encountered it in an article on Euler’s derivation of the gamma function. Euler begins by evaluating the integral:

$$\int_0^1 x^a(1-x)^n\,dx$$

He performs a binomial expansion on the integrand and makes use of the following identity involving alternating binomial coefficients:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k {n \choose k} \frac{1}{a+k+1} = n! \prod_{k=0}^{n}\left( \frac{1}{a+k+1} \right).$$

It is not obvious to me on inspection that this formula is true, but I have found it cited elsewhere in the mathematical literature, without proof. I have verified it by hand for the cases of n=2 and n=3, but I am unable to prove the identity in general. I am looking for a good combinatorial or inductive proof of this very interesting fact.

I am aware that this formula relates to the beta function, but I am trying to derive this relationship without reference to this topic.

Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: Thanks for this great response, which exposed me to some new concepts with which I was not familiar.

Comment: just wanted to note a place where a proof can be found in the literature: see R. L. Graham, D. E. Knuth, and O. Patashnik, _Concrete Mathematics_, second edition, page 188.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure if this counts as a duplicate but I give three proofs of an identity equivalent to this identity [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903170/identity-regarding-gamma-function-kind-of/3903758?) (one of which is the beta function proof). I think it is cleanest to write it as

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{z + k} {n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{z(z + 1) \dots (z + n)}$$

(here $z$ is $a+1$) which makes it clearer that for $n$ fixed it is an equality between two rational functions of $z$; in particular it holds for all complex values of $z \neq 0, -1, \dots -n$, and written this way it can be proven by calculating the residues at each pole of the RHS and verifying that they line up with the coefficients of the LHS. I give another proof via thinking of the LHS as the $n^{th}$ finite difference of the sequence $a_k = \frac{1}{z + k}$, which can be computed by induction and verified to line up with the RHS.

If we substitute $z \mapsto -\frac{1}{z}$ and clear denominators we get the equivalent identity

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{1 - kz} {n \choose k} = \frac{n! z^n}{(1 - z) \dots (1 - nz)}$$

which is an ordinary generating function identity for the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Generating_functions), and which can be proven by proving an exponential generating function identity and then translating it over.

Comment: yes, it is a known expansion of the falling factorial with integral negative index $$
\left( {z - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - \left( {n + 1} \right)\,} }  = {1 \over {z^{\,\overline {\,n + 1\,} } }}\; = {1 \over {z\left( {z + 1} \right) \cdots \left( {z + n} \right)}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

By the partial fractions theorem, we know
$$\frac{n!}{a(a+1) \cdots (a+n+1)} = \frac{b_0}{a} + \frac{b_1}{a+1} + \dots + \frac{b_{n+1}}{a+n+1}$$
for some set of numbers $b_0, b_1, \dots , b_{n+1}$. To find $b_k$, multiply both sides of the equation by $b+k$ and then set $a=-k$ in the resulting equation.  The result is
$$b_k = (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}$$

Answer (score 0):

In trying to evaluate

$$S_n = \sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r {n\choose r} \frac{1}{r+a+1}$$

where $a$ is not in $\{-1, -2, \ldots, -n-1\}$
we introduce

$$f(z) = \frac{(-1)^n \times n!}{z+a+1}
\prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{z-q}$$

which has the property that for $0\le r\le n$

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=r} f(z) =
\frac{(-1)^n \times n!}{r+a+1}
\prod_{q=0}^{r-1} \frac{1}{r-q}
\prod_{q=r+1}^n \frac{1}{r-q}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n \times n!}{r+a+1}
\frac{1}{r!} \frac{(-1)^{n-r}}{(n-r)!}
= (-1)^r {n\choose r} \frac{1}{r+a+1}.$$

It follows that

$$S_n = \sum_{r=0}^n \mathrm{Res}_{z=r} f(z).$$

Now residues sum to zero and the residue at infinity of $f(z)$ is zero
by inspection, therefore

$$S_n = - \mathrm{Res}_{z=-1-a} f(z) =
(-1)^{n+1} \times n! \times
\prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{-1-a-q}
\\ = n! \prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{a+q+1}.$$

This is the claim.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the "clearest" way to demonstrate the identity is through
the [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) and
the [Falling and Rising Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) as follows

The finite difference (unitary step) of a function wrt to the variable $z$ is defined as
$$
\Delta _{\,z} \,f(z) = f(z + 1) - f(z)
$$
and its iteration becomes
$$
\Delta _{\,z} ^{\,n} \,f(z) = \Delta _{\,z} \,\left( {\Delta _{\,z} ^{\,n - 1} \,f(z)} \right)
 = \sum\limits_k {\left( { - 1} \right)^{n - k}
 \left( \matrix{  n \cr   k \cr}  \right)\;f(z + k)} 
$$

Now, concerning the function $1/z$ we have
$$
\eqalign{
  & \Delta _{\,z} \left( {{1 \over z}} \right) = {1 \over {z + 1}} - {1 \over z}
 = {{ - 1} \over {z\left( {z + 1} \right)}}  \cr 
  & \Delta _{\,z} ^{\,2} \left( {{1 \over z}} \right)
 = \Delta _{\,z} \left( {\Delta _{\,z} \left( {{1 \over z}} \right)} \right)
 = {{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,2} 2} \over {z\left( {z + 1} \right)\left( {z + 2} \right)}}  \cr 
  & \;\quad  \vdots   \cr 
  & \Delta _{\,z} ^{\,n} \left( {{1 \over z}} \right)
 = \Delta _{\,z} ^{\,n} \left( {\left( {z - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - 1\,} } } \right)
 = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n\,} } \left( {z - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - 1 - n\,} }
  = {{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} n!} \over {z^{\,\overline {\,n + 1\,} } }} \cr} 
$$
where the last line follows from the fundamental properties of the [Falling and Rising Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)
represented respectively with  $x^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } ,\quad x^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } $.

Putting the two together
$$
\Delta _{\,z} ^{\,n} \left( {{1 \over z}} \right)
 = {{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} n!} \over {z^{\,\overline {\,n + 1\,} } }}
 = \sum\limits_k {\left( { - 1} \right)^{n - k} \left( \matrix{  n \cr  k \cr}  \right)\;{1 \over {z + k}}}
 \quad \left| {\;0 \le n \in Z} \right.
$$